# Django nginx+uwsgi *1 connect() to unix:/run/uwsgi/firstsitecd.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Django application on Ubuntu 16.4. I referred a document to deploy my application and here this is the URL which I have followed [server-django-nginx-with-uwsgi](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Everything went good until I faced this issued.

```
*1 connect() to unix:/run/uwsgi/firstsitecd.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

My socket file location

```
/run/uwsgi/firstsitecd
```

permission provided for the socket file

```
f: /run/uwsgi/firstsitecd.sock
 drwxr-xr-x root    root     /
 drwxr-xr-x root    root     run
 drwxr-xr-x iradmin www-data uwsgi
 srwxrwxrwx root    root     firstsitecd.sock
```

**/etc/uwsgi/sites/firstsitecd.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
project = firstsitecd
uid = ******
base = /home/%(uid)

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

In .ini I have tried with `chmod-socket = 660` & `chmod-socket = 666` but nothing helps me.

**/etc/nginx/site-available/firsitecd**

```
server {
    listen 92;
    server_name my_ubuntu_ip_address;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
        root /home/******/firstsitecd;
    }
    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/firstsitecd.sock;
    }
}
```

I tired with plethora of suggestion but nothing helps.

Thanks

Comment: can  please check whether the uwsgi socket is created or not ?? `ls /run/uwsgi/firstsitecd.sock` can you run this command and check??

Comment: Did you start the uwsgi process? How?

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is how I started my uwsgi process - sudo systemctl start uwsgi

Comment: @NakulNarayanan when I run the above command - I am getting this result - /run/uwsgi/firstsitecd.sock